# Zephyr OS understanding

Tags: bluetooth, zephyr-rtos

Initially I built the Zephyr bluetooth application for native linux and run it in conjunction with Bluez on a BLE controller.I understand that in this, Linux OS and Bluez are used along with Zephyr host stack.

Now, I have flashed bluetooth application from Zephyr stack (samples/bluetooth/beacon)to NXP board successfully. Here there is no bluez used.
For this case, I have a few basic understanding questions: 
1. Is the OS functionality also embedded in the bin file that is created after application is compiled. I mean I understand bluetooth stack is Zephyr, but  which OS is used on board ?
2. Also, is there any functionality similar to hcitool in Bluez in Zephyr bluetooth stack?
3. Is there any functionality like btmon or hcidump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:-

1. Zephyr is an OS itself - it is a Real-Time Operating System (RTOS)
   that runs on top of many different types of hardware, just like how
   Linux is an operating system that runs on top of many different
   hardware. Zephyr is mainly written in C and under the hood talks
   directly to the specific processor using its registers and the
   vendor's stack. You can find a list of all supported boards
   [here](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/boards/index.html).
2. Not identical to hcitool, but there is an hci layer example that
   allows you to send raw hci commands. You can find more details on
   this [here](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/samples/bluetooth/hci_uart/README.html#) and [here](https://bcdevices.github.io/zephyr/ble/2019/10/30/zephyr-ble-testing.html). At the end of the day, you may not
   need to use hci because it is a low layer and you can probably
   achieve the same functionality through higher leve API. All Zephyr's
   Bluetooth examples can be found [here](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/samples/bluetooth/hci_uart/README.html#).
3. Again, nothing like btmon on Linux how you can see the raw HCI
   packets for each command, but Zephyr does support different
   Bluetooth logging options depending on the hardware used. More
   information on this can be found [here](https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/zephyr/guides/bluetooth/bluetooth-dev.html).

I hope this helps.